# How to define file path in a view method in django views.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I need to read a CSV file in my view method. This is my view method in views.py in django project:

```
def myfile(request):
    csv_fp = open('file.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_fp)
    headers = [col for col in reader.fieldnames]
    out = [row for row in reader]
    return render(request, 'myfile.html', {'data' : out, 'headers' : headers})
```

This is in my urls.py:
`path('myfile/', views.myfile, name='myfile'),`

My django version is: 3.2.2

I tried many ways to open file in `csv_fp = open('file.csv', 'r')`.

I used the below ways in my views.py and non of them worked:

my file in the static directory:

```
csv_fp = open('static/file.csv' , 'r')    # not working
```

```
csv_fp = open('file.csv' , 'r')    # not working
```

I added the below lines in my views.py and it didn't work as well:

```
import csv, os
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
file_path = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'file.csv') 
csv_fp = open(file_path , 'r')
```

This is the error message:

> Exception Location:   /home/djangoir/virtualenv/project/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template

The point is I don't want to generate a model for the database and import CSV file into the database. I just need somehow read the file and export its data in a dictionary in the render method.

Comment: No, "paths" in urls.py are for url/http request dispatcher, they have nothing to do with "files on drive" work. Use `os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, file.csv')`

Comment: I tried to import:  from django.conf import settings  and then file_path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'file.csv'). But it didn't work as well.

Comment: `it didn't work` is not technically specific enough. Please post full traceback of the actual exception.

Comment: same exception error as mentioned in question:

Comment: Exception Location: /home/djangoir/virtualenv/project/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template

Comment: If you didn't resolve this yet, add your full error traceback

Comment: I just understood some valid points about my question. Actually,  the file path in my question is fine and valid. The point is, this view function, returns a big dictionary and maybe render could not handle this. I used another solution with my original file path and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: What runs your application is the manage.py file. Therefore every file routing has to be done relative to the manage.py file.

Having said that you need a file structure similar like this:

```
my_project/
    my_app/
        static/
        files/
            file.csv
        admin.py
        apps.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        ...
    my_project/
        __init__.py
        wsgi.py
        settings.py
        ...
    manage.py
```

Then your view can be:

```
import os

def myfile(request):
    fp = os.path.join("my_app/files/file.csv")
    csv_fp = open(fp, 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_fp)
    headers = [col for col in reader.fieldnames]
    out = [row for row in reader]
    return render(request, 'myfile.html', {'data' : out, 'headers' : headers})
```

I would try to avoid connecting it to your static files. The point of static files is to be served directly by your server/proxy (e.g. nginx), but if I understand you correctly, you don't want that. Instead of serving it directly, without modification to the user, you want to "do stuff" with read csv file first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just understood some valid points about my question. Actually, this file path you mentioned above and the file path in my original question both are fine and valid. The point is, this view function, returns a big dictionary and maybe render could not handle this. I used another solution with my original file path and it worked well.